# JSON Data is not fetched to Signuser model class properties to view properties in segued view controller labels in viewdidload

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a model class of all string variables which i need to display in home view controller when user is successfully logged in.

I have created a seperate function to fetch and assign stuffs from user profile api and assign to model class.
and it's called in login function.

but after the segue to next view controller,Model class variables are still blank in it's viewdidload.(consider it as any viewcontroller )

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  var countries = [String]()
  var cities = [String]()
  let manager = APIManager()

  @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




}


@IBAction func ForgotPasswordAction(_ sender: UIButton) {



}

@IBAction func LoginButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let username = self.txtUsername.text
    let password = self.txtPassword.text

    if (username?.isEmpty)! || (password?.isEmpty)!{

        self.showAlertWith(title: "Empty Username / Password", message: "Please check if username or password is entered")

    }
    else {
        if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet{

            let parameter:Parameters = ["userItsId":username!,"password":password!]

            manager.parsing2(url: BaseURL.login, parameter: parameter) { (JSON, Status) in

                if Status {    //login success

                    self.fetchUserProfile()

                    if JSON["status"] == "true"{

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender:self)


                    }
                    else{

                        print("login failed")
                    }


                }
                else {

                    print("error occured,try again later")

                }

            }

        }
        else {
            self.showAlertWith(title: "No Internet", message: "Please make sure that your device is connected to internet")
        }


    }


}

@IBAction func NotMemberAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "register", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func SkipButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet {

        user.isLoggedin = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skip", sender: self )

    }
    else {
        self.showAlertWith(title: "Connectivity Error", message: "Please check your connection and make sure that you are connected to the internet")

    }

}

func fetchUserProfile(){
    let userid = txtUsername.text
    let parameter:Parameters = ["userItsId":userid!]
    manager.parsing2(url: BaseURL.profile, parameter: parameter) { (JSON, Status) in

        if Status{

            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject!
            let data = dict["data"] as! [String:String]

                let username = data["userName"]
                let email = data["email"]
                let UserId = data["userId"]
                let nationality = data["nationality"]
                let country = data["country"]
                let mCity = data["mCity"]
                let phoneNo = data["phoneNo"]
                let dawatTitle = data["dawatTitle"]
                let itsId = data["itsId"]

                signUser.name = username!
                signUser.email = email!
                signUser.userID = UserId!
                signUser.nationality = nationality!
                signUser.country = country!
                signUser.mCity = mCity!
                signUser.phone = phoneNo!
                signUser.dawatName = dawatTitle!
                signUser.ItsId = itsId!


        }
        else {

            print("fetching failed")

        }

    }


}

}
```

Comment: @HichemRomdhane You use a tag with specific Swift version for questions directly related to changes that have been made for this Swift version. This is a general Swift question, so those tags are not relevant.

Comment: where have you declared "signUser" ??

Comment: as i already told you...it is model class with globa; variables.And it's declared outside  in a seperate swift file.You dont have to focus on it.

Comment: once you have initialised it then you don't have to initialise again and again so that's why it's needed for me to identify where exactly you are initialising it

Comment: I am using static variables and it works.Can you please help me to figure out the problem in code